# maven force continue if one module fails

Tags: maven

I have a 'master' pom file that includes multiple modules. I want maven to continue to build even if one module fails, instead of skipping the rest. Which option/configuration should I use? Thanks

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Fail at end should work in your scenario.

Basic Def from Maven Specs :

```
--fail-at-end - if a particular module build fails, continue the rest of the reactor
           and report all failed modules at the end instead .
```

Comment: hey, tks for answer, how do I put this option directly in the pom or setting file, since I run maven plugin in intelliJ, not from commandline.

Comment: assuming you have the maven plugin installed for Intellij , you can run it as maven module set the goal like -
              `clean install -fae`

Answer (score 36):

You can use the command line option:

```
--fail-at-end
```

should be your friend.