# Maven: pass the build even if one module fails

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I am trying to generate an aggregate Jacoco code coverage report by following the steps [here](https://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Maven/Chapter_06_-_Jacoco_report_aggregation.jsp).
My initial maven project may contain multiple modules and I add an aggregator module `aggregator` to the main pom dynamically through my code.

The folder structure looks somewhat like this (there can be any number of modules and sub modules in the main project):

```
/SampleProject/
-- pom.xml
-- module1/
---- pom.xml
---- src/
-- module2/
---- pom.xml
---- src/
-- module3/
---- pom.xml
---- src/
-- aggregator/
---- pom.xml
```

This is the main pom:

**SampleProject/pom.xml** . (here, the aggregator module is added dynamically through my code)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>sampleProject</name>

    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
        <module>module3</module>
        <module>aggregator</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Each module has its own pom.xml. and the aggregator pom (which is generated by my code) looks something like this (each module is added as a dependency in this pom. This information is fetched from the individual poms of the modules):

**aggregator/pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>sampleProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>aggregator</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sample.module1</groupId>
            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sample.module2</groupId>
            <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sample.module3</groupId>
            <artifactId>module3</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${argLine} -Xms256m -Xmx2048m</argLine>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <runOrder>random</runOrder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report-aggregate</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and, to generate the aggregate report I use the following command:

`mvn clean test -DskipTests=false`

This generates the aggregate report in 'aggregator/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/index.html'

Now, the problem is if something goes wrong with only the aggregator build, and that build fails (but all other modules' build is successful). Then the maven output will look something like this:

```
[INFO] module1 .......................................... SUCCESS [  2.197 s]
[INFO] module2 .......................................... SUCCESS [ 11.287 s]
[INFO] module3 .......................................... SUCCESS [  6.969 s]
[INFO] aggregator ....................................... FAILURE [  1.241 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 00:21 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-26T13:01:12-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 258M/1149M
```

Which means that the overall build is also marked as failed if just the aggregator part fails. This causes problem in the next step in the deployment pipeline.

So, what I want is that even if the aggregator build is failing, the overall build should be marked as passed (i.e. ignore the failing aggregator build) so that I can proceed with the next step in deployment, so that not generating the code coverage report, does not fail my entire deployment process. (I will handle the missing code coverage report later in the process).

Is there some way to achieve this? any help would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE 1**:

I already check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942994/maven-force-continue-if-one-module-fails) answer and this is not what I want. Using `-fae` flag in maven would still mark the build as failed at the end.

Also, I do not want the `-fn` flag either because then I would be ignoring actual build failures in the modules as well, which is not desired.

What I'm looking for is a way to ignore the failures of just one module in maven.

I'm not really sure if doing that is possible, any alternate suggestions are welcome too.

---

**UPDATE 2**:

Update and some background info.:

So, I am building this tool as kind of a central tool which runs on all projects so it should be generic enough to cater to different types of configurations, without changing anything in the main project (on which the tests are being run).

As of now, it seems what I am looking for is not possible. So, as a workaround, I am asking the main project's owner to include a config file which tells my tool which packages to be included for code coverage.

Will update here if I find a better solution or workaround.

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17942994

Comment: I already checked this, This does not answer my question, as it will still mark the build as failed at the end and the output is exactly the same as the one I mentioned above int he question.

Comment: What is exact reason of failure of "aggregator" module? AFAIK `report-aggregate` not supposed to fail at all, except if it can't read/write from/to disk, but then you have other far more serious problem.

Comment: I checked, the reason for failure is that is is not able to find some of the dependencies. The exact error is:

`Failed to execute goal on project aggregator: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sample:aggregator:jar:1.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.sample.module2:module2:jar:0.1, ….`

Comment: So fix the dependencies, or don't build this module at all (`-pl \!aggregator`).

Comment: hmm, So, I won't be able to fix those dependencies as I am not the owner of that code. But I think maybe you are right. The only option that I have is to not build the modules with incorrect dependencies in this case.
One workaround that I could think of was to not add those dependencies in the aggregator pom at all so that the overall build would never fail.

Comment: It might be a workaround if report was generated from execution of maven-invoker-plugin - it can record errors of the built modules, but without failing the main build.

Comment: maven-invoker-plugin is for integration tests, but this is needed during the unit test phase.